# How does compiler(gcc) know whether a function is to be dynamically linked or not?

Tags: c

For example,`printf` is dynamically linked.

But how does the compiler(gcc) know that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc doesn't know that. It knows there is a function `printf` and it knows how to call it, but the object file it generates contains a call to an unresolved symbol.

The symbol is then resolved by the linker, which is given all your object files and libraries. The linker finds the symbol `printf` in a library, and after its combined all the relevant modules, it updates the unresolved calls.

Comment: How does it know whether `printf` should be resolved statically(link time) or dynamically(run time)?

Comment: The compiler leaves a placeholder for a call to `printf`. It has no knowledge of where the function is so it just calls to some bogus address and flags it for the linker to fix up. The linker knows this function lives in a dynamically loaded library (you tell it so), and flags it for the OS loader to fix up. The OS then resolves this at load time, when it loads the library (or maybe has it's already loaded) and it knows the real address of `printf`.

Comment: Right,that's how procedure link table works,but how does the linker know whether a function like `printf` should be resolved by OS or itself in the first place? **How** do we tell it?

Comment: You explicitly tell the linker, e.g. with `-Bdynamic` for gnu ld, or flag the symbol, e.g. with `__declspec(dllexport)` for MS Visual C. Some part of your toolchain might do this for you (e.g. GNU Libtool).

Comment: But I  never touch those flags,I just compile my programe by `gcc example.c` and done.

Comment: By default gcc will pass the appropriate flags to the linker to use dynamic linking. If you add the -static option, gcc will pass the appropriate options for the linker to link statically.

Comment: @janneb,Which library provides statlic link for `printf`?

Comment: @mysql_go: On my system (Ubuntu amd64) it's in /usr/lib/libc.a ; As you haven't specified which OS you use, I can't answer where it lives on your system.